# Cast Queried Results To Tuple

Tags: c#

I am attempting to create a function that will take the results of a database query and put them into a generic tuple. I have code that successfully works when querying Sql Server or Sybase databases but I'm having difficulty making it work with an OleDb connection to an excel document.

Usage Example:

```
var myTuple = excelConnection.ExecuteTuple<(string, string, int)>("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", new OleDbParameter[0])
```

Here is the code I'm using for Sql Server and Sybase to convert the results just updated to use OleDb:

```
public T ExecuteValue<T>(string sqlStatement, IEnumerable<OleDbParameter> parameters) where T : ITuple
{
    using var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    using var command = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    T results = default;
    int tupleFields = results.Length;

    // Read the results into the tuple
    reader.Read();

    for (int i = 0; i < tupleFields; ++i)
    {
        object tupleObject = results;

        //Set the values of the Tuple
        var setValue = reader.GetValue(i) == DBNull.Value ? default : reader.GetValue(i);

        //This call fails to set the value.
        //If the tuple doesn't match the exact type its stored in excel as.
        //So all numeric values must be cast to double.
        results.GetType().GetField($"Item{i + 1}").SetValue(tupleObject, setValue);

        results = (T)tupleObject;
    }

    return results;
}
```

When working with individual values I am able to do this:

```
result = reader.GetValue(0) == DBNull.Value ? default :(T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.GetValue(0), typeof(T));
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to use the type of that individual element of the tuple in a cast like is being done with the individual values.

Comment: Just pass `null`, it will set to `default` automatically. You don't need `object tupleObject = results;` just use `result` everywhere. `reader` needs a `using`

Comment: The issue is with casting the data field. Added additional notes for clarity.